# Problem installing QGIS 3.12 on Linux KDE neon

Tags: qgis, installation

I tried to install both versions QGIS 3.10.x and QGIS 3.12 on KDE neon from the https://qgis.org/ubuntu and https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr repositories but without success (unlike in Ubuntu 18.04 and linux Mint 19.3 ).
I have the following output in konsole Terminal Emulator:

```
andrea@andrea-Z390:~$ sudo apt-get install qgis python3-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Investigating (0) qgis:amd64 < none -> 1:3.12.0+28bionic @un puN Ib >
Broken qgis:amd64 Depends on qgis-providers:amd64 < none | 1:3.12.0+28bionic @un uH > (= 1:3.12.0+28bionic)
  Considering qgis-providers:amd64 0 as a solution to qgis:amd64 10000
  Re-Instated qgis-providers-common:amd64
    Reinst Failed early because of qtbase-abi-5-9-5:amd64
Investigating (0) python3-qgis:amd64 < none -> 1:3.12.0+28bionic @un puN Ib >
Broken python3-qgis:amd64 Depends on qgis-providers:amd64 < none | 1:3.12.0+28bionic @un uH > (= 1:3.12.0+28bionic)
  Considering qgis-providers:amd64 0 as a solution to python3-qgis:amd64 10000
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-qgis : Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:3.12.0+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
 qgis : Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:3.12.0+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment with my user status yet, so I have to write my suggestions/comment as an answer.

I'm facing the same problems with kde neon.
If you run `sudo apt install qgis-providers python3-qgis qgis qgis-plugin-grass` to install the depending packages as well you'll get probably the message "qtbase-abi-5-12-8" is missing, even if "libqt5core5a" (the main package for it) is already installed and updated. And this seems to be a long known [KDE neon-specific issue](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=139667).

A solution for you might be [installing QGIS via Flatpak](https://www.flathub.org/apps/details/org.qgis.qgis). Unfortuately this is no solution for me because I need the SAGA tools in QGIS, wich are not available in the Flatpak installation. So if someone has a better solution for installing QGIS via apt please share.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky because it seems that the virtual qtbase-abi-5-12-8 package is missing in KDE Neon. In Ubuntu this one is provided by libqt5core5a but KDE Neon updated most of the Qt stuff.

I tried to remove the depend in the qgis-providers package of the default repo and the own QGIS repo without success (you will get a dynamic linking error to the Qt3DExtras).

What you could do is to build and install QGIS from the source-code. It will take some time but is not so difficult (see here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL.md) and worked for me!

This issue is also listed by QGIS and KDE Neon,
see:

- https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=252&t=155594&p=432866&hilit=qgis#p432866
- https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/36555